# Are these two structs equivilant?

Tags: c

I'm a bit new to structs and just wondering if these two structs are equivalent. I dont know if this is relevant, but im using these structs to build a stack.

Is this:

```
struct dataT
{
    int m;
};

struct stack
{
    int top;
    struct dataT items[100];
} st;
```

equivalent to this?

```
struct stack
    {
        int top;
        int items[100];
    } st;
```

Arent these basically the same? The second method only uses one struct.
If im wrong, could you please tell me why it is not.

Comment: absolutely not. access methods will be different.

Comment: Yea, but structre vise they are the same right? Why are we creating another struct if you can just do it the way I did it the second way, this way there is only 1 strcut. This is what is confusing me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will make a difference if you ever decide to change the `dataT` structure. If you know that it will always be only a wrapper for `int`, then it is a pretty useless structure. But if it may change, then the top one will probably be easier to maintain.

Comment: With the program I am building it will always be the same. I will not be adding anything  other than the int in the struct. So the second method is better and will function the same way in this case right?

Comment: Yeah, I don't see any reason to use the top version, it seems to be unnecessarily complex. The second way is functionally equivalent in terms of data storage.